# Input-group with negative margin-bottom display issue when focusing on input

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap input groups and applying the negative margin `margin-bottom: -1px` similar to this example:

http://getbootstrap.com/examples/signin/

However, if you look at the screenshot below, when I focus on an input, the negative margin causes the bottom highlight of the input to be hidden.

[image: Bootstrap input-group input with margin-bottom: -1px]

Can anybody suggest how to resolve this?

I was hoping for an obvious answer perhaps explaining why this doesn't happen on the Bootstap signin example.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tH36x/)

Comment: Does your input have a `position:relative;` ?

Comment: It does. I've added a fiddle - see above. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should solve the issue.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SchmalzyB/tH36x/1/)

```
.form-control:focus {
   z-index: 2;
}
```

When dealing with focus events\stylings, you can use the Developer Tools to force the focus state on an input and see whats going on (at least in Chrome you can...). Just right-click on an element's HTML and select "Force element state"->":focus"

Comment: Thanks very much. That works but I don't understand why it's necessary in my case when it isn't necessary in the bootstrap sign-in example.

Comment: Ah - sorry. it is there in the sign-in example :) Thanks again. Answer accepted.